# cant use ng-show and ng-hide in angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

I am trying to access data from my angular's controller. The file is as follows. The following is the scope and variables associated.

- The idea is that when the statusCode is 401, the invalid_login must become true.
- And when the statusCode is 200 (else condition below), the logged_in must become true.

The idea is that when

```
 $scope.invalid_login    = true;
        $scope.unexpected_error = false;
        $scope.logged_in        = false;


        $http({

            method: "POST",
            url: "/getUserInfo",

            data: {

                "username"        : $scope.username,

            }

        }).success(function(data) {

            if (data.statusCode == 401) {

                $scope.invalid_login    = false;
                $scope.unexpected_error = true;
                $scope.logged_in = false;

                alert('Status Code: '+data.statusCode);

            } else if(data.statusCode == 200){

                console.log('FROM LOGINCONTROLLER : ' + data.username);
                console.log('Status Code : ' + data.statusCode);

                $scope.username         = data.username;
                alert('Status Code: '+data.statusCode);
                $scope.invalid_login    = false;
                $scope.unexpected_error = false;
                $scope.logged_in        = true;


            }

        }).error(function(error) {

            $scope.logged_in        = false;        
            $scope.unexpected_error = true;
            $scope.invalid_login    = true;

        });
```

When I try to access this in my ejs, it does not reflect expected behavior.

- I want to show **Sign In or Register** option when a user is not logged in : (logged_in = false and invalid_login = true).
- And want to show a logged in view(with options for sign out) when (logged_in = true and invalid_login = false)

The following is a snippet from my ejs:

```
<div class                             ="dropdown"  ng-hide="true" style="font-size:small; text-decoration:none; margin-top:6px;">

                                    <a class                       ="dropdown">
                                        <a href                    ="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#555555" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Hi! <b>{{username}}</b><b class="caret"></b></a>

                                        <ul class                  ="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-1">

                                            <div class             ="row">

                                                <div class         ="col-sm-12">
                                                    <ul class      ="multi-column-dropdown">

                                                        <li class  ="h4"><b><a href="#">My Collection</a></b></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
                                                        <li><form action="logout" method="post">
                                                            <input type="submit" value="Logout"  class="btn btn-success"/>
                                                        </form></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Antiques</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Sports Memorabilia</a></li>
                                                        <li class  ="divider"></li>
                                                        <li class  ="h4"><b><a href="#">Electronics</a></b></li>
                                                        <li>

                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Coins & Paper Money</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Antiques</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#">Sports Memorabilia</a></li>


                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </ul>
                                    </a>
                                </a>
                            </div>



                            <a ng-show="invalid_login">


                            Sign In or Register


                            </a>




                            </li>
                            <li>
```

Comment: $http success won't fire when request status is a 200 series and `data` is the server response. So either you are misunderstanding how $http works or you are sending unusual responses from server. Show how you send responses from server

Comment: Also should be more specific about what *"does not reflect expected behavior"* means

Comment: .success and .error is deprecated. I would suggest moving to the .then standard.

Comment: Edit: should say above *"$http success won't fire when request status is **not** a 200 series"*

Comment: When status code == 401, you code does not reflect logic you have described

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the latest angular 1 version (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js)

> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated.
>   Use the standard `then` method instead.

it is deprecated but still supported, its code is:

```
    promise.success = function(fn) {
      assertArgFn(fn, 'fn');

      promise.then(function(response) {
        fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
      });
      return promise;
    };
```

*response.status* is passed to the callback function as second parameter, so you should check it like

```
.success(function(data, statusCode) {

        if(statusCode === 200){

            console.log('FROM LOGINCONTROLLER : ' + data.username);
            console.log('Status Code : ' + data.statusCode);

            $scope.username         = data.username;
            alert('Status Code: '+data.statusCode);
            $scope.invalid_login    = false;
            $scope.unexpected_error = false;
            $scope.logged_in        = true;


        }
}).error(function(error, statusCode) {
        // will be false only for 401 status
        $scope.logged_in        = statusCode !== 401;        
        $scope.unexpected_error = true;
        $scope.invalid_login    = true;

        alert('Status Code: ' + statusCode);
    });
```

and the best would be to move to *then(successFunction, errorFunction, notifyFunction)* instead of *success*, but then you data will be under *response.data*, and status code under *response.status*

SUCCESS status codes are 200-299 (including), the rest statuses will be caught by errorFunction

Comment: still not going to catch 401 in success

Comment: you are absolutely right, it should be caught in deprecated .error function or in errorFunction of then